# Clear field value when edit node

Tags: forms, hooks

I have a List (text) field in a content type that will determine the importance of the content whether it is Major or Minor and that field is set to be required. I need to force content editors to make that selection each time they edit a content page. Is there a way to clear the data from that field upon edit event?

Note: I'm on Drupal 9.2.18

Comment: If I got it right, HOOK_form_alter should be ok, then set the field[YOURFIELD]['default_value'] = NULL;

Comment: Remember to specify which version of Drupal you're using.

Comment: @HodbaKhalaf. The hook_form_alter worked only the NULL value was rejected so I replaced it ' ' and that solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: @Lambic Sorry for not specifying Drupal version, it's 9.2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HOOK_form_alter should be ok, then empty the field default value.

```
$form[YOURFIELD]['default_value'] = '';
```